# What is Solr differential update execution time?

Tags: mysql, database, solr4

I am a newbie on Solr. I have set up the basics and is working properly. Now, I am using DIH for importing data from MySql. I will be using differential update for every update/insert in the MySql table. I want to know the approximate execution time. I cannot find any documentation on execution time.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I've never even heard of differential update with respect to Solr.  Do you mean Atomic Updates?

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates

The amount of time that an atomic update takes is approximately the amount of time required to retrieve the existing record using the uniqueKey field value plus the amount of time required to index the new document, representing the retrieved values modified by the changes requested.

If you don't mean atomic updates, what DO you mean?